# Python: Delete a char by char from a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to delete character by character from a string (each time a single character to see what the string is going to look like)

```
var = 'string'
var1 = ''
cor = []
for i in range(0, len(var)):
    varl = var[:i] + var[(i+1):]
    cor.append(varl)
print (cor)
```

This is what am getting

```
['t', 'sr', 'sti', 'strn', 'strig', 'tring', 'sring', 'sting', 'strng', 'strig', 'strin']
```

I don't know why am getting the first 5 elements in the list, they should not exist.
Does anyone know how to fix this, Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce...

Comment: did you debug your program step by step? that should reveal what's wrong...

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 64-bit cpython and getting the desired result rather than what's above

Comment: @JohnKane same here

Comment: You could change the whole thing to: `cor = [var[:i] + var[i+1:] for i in range(len(var))]`. This is called list comprehension. What does that give you?

Comment: Am using python 3.6 64-bit as well

Comment: and yes am debugging it step by step

Comment: @Ran just noticed something - there's unsused `var1` (ends with 1, not with L) - why is that? perhaps it has something to do with it?

Comment: @AntonvBR That worked for me, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really any reason for this not to work. However, using list comprehension instead, seeing as it solved your problem:

```
var = 'string'
cor = [var[:i] + var[i+1:] for i in range(len(var))]
print (cor)
```

Returns

```
['tring', 'sring', 'sting', 'strng', 'strig', 'strin']
```

The main reason your output seems strange is the loop which should add len(var) variables max.

```
for i in range(0, len(var)):
```

Comment: `[var[:i] + var[(i+1):] for i, _ in enumerate(var)]` is a cleaner version.

Answer (score 0):

In your variable definitions, you have the second variable defined as `var1` (i.e. var'one'), and in your for loop, you have `varl` (i.e. var'el').

Change `varl`s in your loop to `var1` and you'll have what you expect.

Comment: Wow... super ninja'd while I was testing and typing. :(

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer? It is CORRECT, even though the accepted answer is more efficient.

Comment: You are welcome! The ability to notice the difference between 1 and l is always a life-saver, plus the original code really does work correctly after fixing this issue.

Comment: I think this may have been downvoted before because `var1` and `varl` have nothing to do with each other in the original code. OP's code should work as posted.

Comment: Ahh, yeah you're right @EricEdLohmar. I typed it quickly into an interpreter instead of pasting it into a .py file like I should have. The code should work as the OP posted it, so even though the answer is a better way, I'm still not sure why he was getting the output he was getting. Thanks all! :)

Comment: @EricEdLohmar you are damn right, it should work as is. Now we know why the downvote. Regardless, distinguishing 1 and l is always a must though :)